# Delphi Splash Screen not closing icons in Taskbar

Tags: delphi, splash-screen, vcl, delphi-xe8

I have used [this](http://delphi.about.com/od/formsdialogs/a/splashscreen.htm) article to create a simple splash screen.  All is working, but after my Splash Screen is freed I still have an extra icon in my taskbar - hence, for one application I have two icons.

[image: Splash screen not closed]

The code in my project file are as follow

```
Application.Initialize;
SplashScreen := TSplashScreen.Create(nil); 
SplashScreen.Show; 
SplashScreen.Update; 
Application.Title := 'Frame';
Application.CreateForm(TMainform, Mainform);
Application.Create;
SplashScreen.Hide; 
SplashScreen.Free;
Application.Run;
```

Comment: We cannot see any code, nor do we know which Delphi version you use

Comment: Hi David.  My apologies.  I am using Delphi XE8.  As far as the code goes, I am using the exact code as was mentioned in my question.

Comment: It's offsite. And it's a pain to read that link. So I won't dig deeper. If there was code in the question I'd try to help.

Comment: Hi David.  Code added as requested.

Comment: Calling `Appplication.Create`? I bet that's not in the article. You probably want to set Application.MainformOnTaskbar` to `True`.

Comment: @David That article seems to suggest there's already a line `Application.Create()` which is of course incorrect. I'm sure the article *meant* to say `Application.CreateForm()`.

Answer (score 1):

It's entirely plausible that the spurious `Application.Create` is the problem. Remove it. The `Hide` is pointless too. Perhaps this is what you need:

```
Application.Initialize;
SplashScreen := TSplashScreen.Create(nil); 
SplashScreen.Show; 
SplashScreen.Update; 
Application.Title := 'Frame';
Application.CreateForm(TMainform, Mainform);
SplashScreen.Free;
Application.Run;
```

You might also wish to consider adding `Application.MainformOnTaskbar := True;` after the call to `Initialize`.

Answer (score 0):

I usually make splash screens by this way:
At OnCreate event (on your main form):

```
  F_Splash := TF_Splash.Create(Self);
  F_Splash.ShowModal;
```

On your splash screen form, drop a TTimer component and set an interval (e.g. 500 milliseconds). On its OnTimer event:

```
  Self.Close;
```

I believe this approach is more useful than the example you mentioned.

Comment: There is a lot going on before the OnCreate event of my form is called, so I need to display the splash screen before the onCreate is executed.  Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

David Heffernan's answer is basically correct. I had that same problem a while back.  I solved it with this:

```
  Application.Initialize;
  SplashScreen := TSplashScreen.Create(nil);
  Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True;
  SplashScreen.Show;
  SplashScreen.Update;
  Application.Title := 'Frame';
  Application.CreateForm(TMainForm, MainForm);
  SplashScreen.Free;
  Application.Run;
```

I also make sure that SplashScreen is not listed as a form in the code, but I do include the SplashUnit in the Uses clause.

This has worked correctly for a couple of years.

Comment: How is this any different from David's answer?

Comment: What I have is tested, it does use the line he says to consider adding (I think it has to be there in that position), and It explains not to have the SplashScreen in the list of forms, but to include the unit in Uses. I just pui it all together in a working version. As I wrote, he is basically correct.

Comment: You meant the list of auto correct forms I presume?

Comment: @David Heffernan, I actually mean the list of Auto-create Forms, and the list of Available Forms. That takes the form out of the uses clause, or you manually delete the form from the Uses clause which removes it from the lists. I manually add the splash form's unit in the Uses clause. It has been a couple of years, but I remember having to play around with this for quite a while before I hit on exactly what worked. I created a generic splash unit that can be added to any of my projects, and it queries for things like the Application name, version number, etc. for use on the splash screen.

Comment: It's fine to have the form in the list of available forms. They key is not using Application.CreateForm to create it because that makes it the main form.

Comment: @David Heffernan, OK, it's just that this was such a pain to get right that, once I got it to work, I didn't want to make any changes to the working formula. I think the real key is setting the `Application.MainformOnTaskbar := True;` immediately after creating the splash screen.

Comment: Why does it matter where that is set? Personally I'd set it after Initialize.

Comment: @David Heffernan, that's possible, too, but I know that the combination I have prevents the behavior about which the OP complains. I, too, started with the article that the OP did, and it was frustrating until I hit the right combination.